# Windows phone 8.1 ad network monetization recommendation

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, ads

Can you please share with me what ad network monetization platform are you using for windows phone 8.1? I am interesting in banners mostly (probably I will add soon video too), and as coverage I want to target europe, usa, global (in this order).

I researched a lot on this topic, and I found quite a lot of recommendations, but some of them no longer apply, since many ad networks are dropping support for windows phone :(.

I have tried several, but I am not happy with the results:

- AdDuplex - the single one that is reliable
- Smaato - the fill rate is extremely low (at its best is 10%. For example currently I have 20k requests a day, and the fill rate is 2.56% over the last 7 days)
- Vmax - integrated through Smaato - 0% fillrate (even if I have requests on India)
- MobFox - integrated through Smaato - they are serving ~20-30% ads, but none of them reaches Smaato (I am considering using the API from MobFox to see how it goes).
- Microsoft Ad - I am not able to make it work. I know they dropped support for AdMediator this year, and I followed their documentation but no luck: the sdk doesn't install, or is missing the control.
- AdRotator - I am using this for mediation purposes, but since from the supported networks only few are still supporting windows phone, I will replace this soon with my own mediation algorithm. (Currently I am using AdRotator with Smaato and AdDuplex)

Is there anyone who can help me on this one?

PS: please do not point me to UWP in order to use Microsoft Ad Control, since in my case, most of my users are wp 8.1 (70-80%).

Thanks!

Comment: Please read the Help section on what to ask here. This is not a programming question and cannot be answered in an objective way.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please share with me what ad network monetization platform are
>   you using for windows phone 8.1?

Based on my personal experience, Microsoft and Ad Duplex network could perform better to my app.

You could refer to **[Selecting and managing your network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn864356.aspx)**.

Since your question intends to be a discussion one which cannot be answered objectively, I'd like to suggest you to open up a discussion thread [**here**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/home?forum=aiasdk) and listen to other community's advice.